# Use the same login credentials with different core versions

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

I have a Drupal 7 site, and I createda  new Drupal 8 site. I would like to use the login credential from the Drupal 7 site in the Drupal 8 site.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes... this is an interesting question.

Comment: @nvahalik The down-vote is probably because it's hard to understand what the OP wants, and doesn't show any effort in finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up the existing Drupal 7 site as an OAuth provider and then set up the Drupal 8 site to allow for OAuth logins and then you could share credentials between the sites.

You won't get any sync for free but at least you wouldn't have to enter the password again.